# Cursor comes up empty in a dynamic user input

Tags: sql, plsql, cursor, sqlplus

I'm currently trying to learn dynamic user input on my own, so based on what research I did, heres the code I came up

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON ;

SET TERMOUT ON;
SET ECHO OFF;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE generateProspect 
    (
    v_cname IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
    )
    AS

    l_cursor sys_refcursor;
    l_query VARCHAR2(512) DEFAULT 'SELECT * FROM prospect ';

    CURSOR l_template IS 
        SELECT * 
        FROM prospect;

    l_rec  l_template%ROWTYPE;


BEGIN



    IF(v_cname IS NOT NULL)
        THEN
        l_query := l_query||'where cname = :v_cname ';
        ELSE
        l_query :=l_query||'where (1=1 or :v_cname IS NULL) ';
    END IF;




    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_query);

        OPEN l_cursor
        FOR l_query
        USING v_cname;

            LOOP
                FETCH l_cursor
                INTO l_rec;

                IF l_cursor%ROWCOUNT =0 THEN
                RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Cursor is empty ');    
                END IF;

                EXIT WHEN l_cursor%NOTFOUND;



                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_rec.cname);
            END LOOP;
        CLOSE l_cursor;

        EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' No data found in database');

        WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Query returns too many rows of data');

        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);

END generateProspect;
/
```

Now , I know that it works if the user input are all empty, however the minute I have values passing from another script of mine that calls this procedure, my user defined error keeps coming up saying, cursor is empty when I know there are values in the prospect table that corresponds to user input.
ex.

```
Talk to me>desc prospect
Name Null? Type
CRAME NOT NULL CHAR(20)
MAKE NOT NULL CHAR(lO)
MODEL CHAR(8)
CYEAR CHAR (4)
COLOR CHAR(l2)
TRIM CEAR(l6)
OCODE CHAR(4) 

Talk to me>select * from prospect where cname='BROCK';
    more...

    CNAME                MAKE       MODEL    CYEA COLOR        TRIM             OCOD
    -------------------- ---------- -------- ---- ------------ ---------------- ----
    BROCK                MERCEDES   M10      2011 BLACK        BLACK            S23


    Talk to me>@tiprospect
    Enter a customer name: BROCK

    Enter an option code: S23
    old  15:        v_cname:= UPPER('&p_cname');
    new  15:        v_cname:= UPPER('BROCK');


    An error was encountered - -20000 -ERROR- ORA-20000: Cursor is empty

    PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

I know that cursor must have fixed length to work and as far as I know it is fixed length, since if user does not input anything, it uses a null value.

So I was wondering if any one can help me determine what I'm doing wrong here, since this is my first time trying to do a dynamic input.

Also in the prospect table, there are cname,make, model,cyear, color,trim ocode as the column names.

[Cursor comes up empty in a dynamic user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20505259/cursor-comes-up-empty-in-a-dynamic-user-input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are using `CHAR` in your table definition.

Your entry for `'BROCK'` for example would be stored as `'BROCK               '` - spaces filling up all the available space.

Change the table definition to use `VARCHAR2` instead and all will work.

Comment: if for whatever reason in a work setting that I can't or dont want to change the table def, what would I need to do, would I need to change my variables to char? How would I modify it such that it would still be a dynamic user input with the same table def?

Comment: just instead of changing table def, I changed the varchar2 to char, and it worked! Thanks

Comment: You could work around it by trimming the value stored to get rid of the extra spaces for the comparison: `where trim(cname) = :v_cname`. Or pad out the variable: `where cname = rpad(:v_cname, 20)`. See [this](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2668391900346844476) AskTom article on VARCHAR2/CHAR.